# jQuery manipulating DIV but not its child elements

Tags: jquery

This is my layout:

```
<div id="outerwrap">
    <div id="innerwrap">
        <div id="centerc">...</div>

        <div id="rightc" style="font-weight:bold">
        </div>
        <div style="background-color:White;height:10px;top:284px;left:0px"></div>

        <div id="leftc">..</div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer" ">...</div>
</div>


<style>
    #outerwrap {
        background-color: #EE44E7;
    }

    #innerwrap {
        background-color: #EE44E7;
        margin-right: 200px;
        top: 0px;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #leftc {
        position: absolute;
        top: 111px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 197px;
        background-color: #EE44E7;
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    #centerc {
        position: relative;
        margin-left: 199px;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: white;
    }

    #rightc {
        position: absolute;
        top: 111px;
        right: 0px;
        width: 199px;
        color: blue;
        background-color: #EE44E7;
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    #footer {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 62px;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
</style>

    #outerwrap
    {
       background-color: #EE44E7;
    }

    #innerwrap
    {
       background-color: #EE44E7;
       margin-right: 200px;
       top:0px;
       height:100%;
    }


    #leftc
    {
       position: absolute;
       top: 111px;
       left: 0px;
       width: 197px;
       background-color: #EE44E7;
       font-size: 10px;
    }

    #centerc
    {
       position: relative;
       margin-left: 199px;
       padding: 0px;
       background-color: white;
    }

    #rightc
    {
       position: absolute;
       top:111px;
       right: 0px;         
       width: 199px;
       color: blue;
       background-color: #EE44E7;
       font-size: 10px;
    }


#footer
    {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 62px;
visibility: hidden;
    }
```

This is the query I wrote:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#leftc").hover(
            function mouseover() {
                $(this).css({ width: "190px" });
                $("#centerc").css({ "margin-left": "195px" });
            },
            function mouseout() {
                $(this).css({ width: "25px" });
                $("#centerc").css({ "margin-left": "29px" });
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

What I want is that when the page loads, the left div should only be partially visible. Now when the user hovers the mouse, the left div(leftc) should expand to 190px. On Hover out, it should return to the partially visible state.

The issue is that the leftc div also has some images and textbox inside it which do not get affected by the code shown above. They remain the same width?

The controls inside the div (leftc) look similar to the following:

```
<div id="leftc">
    <!-- Google Search Box Start -->
    <div id="searchBox">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td> <input name="ctl00$q" type="text" value="Google Custom Search" maxlength="100" id="ctl00_q" onclick="ctl00$q.value=''" onfocus="this.className = 'highlight';" onblur="this.className = '';" style="border-color:#94C7EF;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;" /></td>
                <td align="right">
                    <input type="image" name="ctl00$_btnSearch" id="ctl00__btnSearch" src="images/search.gif" alt="Search" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$_btnSearch&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;SearchGroup&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" />
                </td>
                <td width="5px" align="right">
                    <span id="ctl00__rfvQ" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;"></span>
                    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cx" id="ctl00_cx" value="004354355454353138:kmy_68iupnm" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cof" id="ctl00_cof" value="FORID:11" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!-- Google Search Box End -->


    <br /><br />

    <div id="monthlabel">All this Month</div>
    <div id="monthall">
        <img id="ctl00_imgAuth" src="images/all/Jacor.jpg" style="border-width:0px;" /><br />
        <div style="margin-top:2px;"><a href="http://www.example.com/AllMonth.aspx">Jacor Jul</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you post the inside controls code of the div?

Comment: I have updated the question with contents of the div(leftc)

Answer (score 2):

You should set your left div's style to:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

This will prevent and wrapping or overflow from being shown.

Comment: Thanks..I did that too..still the child elements continue to be of the same size..I also observed that if I call hide() on the leftdiv, all the child elements also get hidden..then why isn't the width changing behavior affecting the child elements..

Comment: What is the behaviour you expect?  You think elements like images or blocks that are full of text will somehow squish themselves when the width is changed?  They won't, they will only try to reflow.